# Angular HttpInterceptor not working when invoking window.location.href

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

Angular HttpInterceptor not working when invoking window.location.href

Have added console.log(request) within interceptor method, but its not getting called.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let req = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
        }
    });
    console.log('request is ' + JSON.stringify(req));
    return next.handle(req);} 

Called below code from a component

window.location.href = 'http://some-ip:some-port/some-path';
```

Comment: Of course it won't work if you go to google, this isn't your website anymore ...

Comment: @trichetriche, sorry just edited the question. Kindly let me know if there is something im doing wrong, as i understand from angular docs, all Http requests should be intercepted, then why for this window.location.href http call, it is not getting called

Comment: Because HTTP requests mean **Angular** http requests, made to an API. `window` requests are handled by the browser, not by you.

Comment: @trichetriche thanks, any clue if i need to invoke external url, basically a url redirection to a different domain, how can i make it via angular HTTP

Comment: You can't. Instead of trying to do something you can't do, tell me what you want to do, I'll tell you how to do it.

Comment: Basically there is redirection happening to OAuth login page, which is the external link. In response to a successful authentication, we have configured the OAuth server to respond back with a token. So now in order to catch that i need to handled the request and to this OAuth external server.

Comment: Then you should append the token to the Angular URL, so that the framework can read it and use it.

Comment: This means that when your authentication is done, and you are redirected to your Angular application, you URL shoud look like this : `http://my.app.com/?token=XXXXXX`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176718/discussion-between-user1119283-and-trichetriche).